# How to find the route that has internet connection and set it as default (lowest metric) with NetworkManager (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, internet, route, networkmanager, metrics

```
~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.30.102  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
default         192.168.137.1   0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 enxd037458b96e3
default         10.64.118.172   0.0.0.0         UG    700    0        0 ppp0
10.64.118.172   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    700    0        0 ppp0
192.168.30.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.137.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 enxd037458b96e3
```

As you can see above, I have 3 gateways managed by NetworkManager, when the interface with the lowest metric loses its connection to internet, the system has no more access to internet. In my case, I want to use the 3G modem (ppp0) to access internet but it doesn't work. It works only if I unplug the interface and it's not feasible in my case (embedded system). You can ignore this interface enxd037458b96e3 (USB Ethernet) that I use for tests.

Is there a solution with NetworkManager (or even without it) ? I don't know how Windows Vista/7/8/10 manages to detect the interface with Internet connection.